Flat File issue while importing
I have a requirement where I have to offload data from SQL server to a pipe separated flat file. Issue is we have a column whose values are typically all special characters that are present on a keyboard.
Since, pipe is also part of data and the delimiter is pipe as well, the file data is getting distorted when downstream system tries to import that generated file from Informatica.
Can anyone please suggest how to deal with this situation. I can't use the idea of escape characters because I have no characters left which are not part of that particular column.
Thanks in advance.

You need to find a character to use either as a delimiter or to enclose fields that is not going to appear in a field. If there is no such character then, as far as I know, it’s not possible to produce a valid delimited file. You could look at the extended ascii character set but then both the application creating the file and the application consuming it would need to be able to work with the chosen character

you can use ^ or find something as per @NickW's advice

Replace the pipe in your data with sth like <thepipesymbol>. No other way around.

You need to enclose fields that contains special characters with double quotes, this way any pipe delimiter within the that field will be ignored, however, when loading that CSV it has to be loaded properly with a tool can handle CSV and not as a string and manually search for delimiters -or include logic for ignoring any delimiters within quotes-.
